# SP - How to Redirect to same page with SPUtility

Tags: sharepoint-server, url, redirect

I want to redirect to the same URL where i'm:

**With this code :**

```
SPUtility.Redirect(this.Page.Request.Url.AbsolutePath, SPRedirectFlags.Default, HttpContext.Current);
```

**Redirect me to the:**

```
http://sf-spsdev02/TestSite/Lists/WayBill/EditForm.aspx
```

**I Want redirect me to same page** :

```
http://sf-spsdev02/TestSite/Lists/WayBill/EditForm.aspx?List=a554a5ff%2Ddbd4%2D4a49%2D8647%2D694310c90930&ID=16&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fsf%2Dspsdev02%2FTestSite%2FLists%2FWayBill%2FAllItems%2Easpx
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery
```

inplace of

```
this.Page.Request.Url.AbsolutePath
```

It will get you the URL with querystring parameteres